# Deploying Web job with appropriate environments variable

Tags: azure-webjobs, octopus-deploy

We are trying to  deploy a web job via octopus. We have different eventhub keys saved in the variables and we expect the webjob to pick up the right key depending on the environment that it is being deployed to. Has one one done this before? Any advice on settings up configurations in octopus?

<========== UPDATE ===========>

We were being careless and didn't quite set our octopus process to transform the  Configuration Variables. You should be able to do so by clicking  'configure variables' in the process step.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990635/how-to-deploy-azure-webjob-using-octopus

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it being deployed via Octopus is all that relevant here. Generally, a .NET WebJob is able to access Azure App Setting using standard configuration API.

If that is not working for you, please update your question to clarify what you tries, and specifically what didn't work.

Comment: We didnt enable the feature to grab variables from "configuration variables". Carelessness on our end.